# Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector required to use MvcRequestMatcher

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

When I run my Spring Boot application I get this error when using this below code:

> Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector required to use MvcRequestMatcher

My pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecommerce</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/bootstrap-datepicker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/jquery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new CustomUserDetailsService();
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
    return config.getAuthenticationManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();

    // return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

 
// @Bean(name = "mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector")
// public HandlerMappingIntrospector mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector() {
// return new HandlerMappingIntrospector();
//   }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("email")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/index")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/admin/logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/home");

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

The error I got:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.1)

2023-01-11T15:41:43.510+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] c.alibou.security.SecurityApplication    : Starting SecurityApplication using Java 17.0.5 with PID 176088 (C:\Users\guruk\Desktop\springboot 3\spring-boot-3-jwt-security-main\target\classes started by guruk in C:\Users\guruk\Desktop\springboot 3\spring-boot-3-jwt-security-main)
2023-01-11T15:41:43.517+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] c.alibou.security.SecurityApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-01-11T15:41:44.558+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-01-11T15:41:44.669+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 83 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-01-11T15:41:45.162+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-01-11T15:41:45.306+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.6.Final
2023-01-11T15:41:45.629+05:30  WARN 176088 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
2023-01-11T15:41:45.810+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-01-11T15:41:46.164+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@11b5f4e2
2023-01-11T15:41:46.169+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-01-11T15:41:46.269+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2023-01-11T15:41:47.131+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-01-11T15:41:47.154+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-01-11T15:41:47.788+05:30  WARN 176088 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/alibou/security/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: No bean named 'A Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is required to use MvcRequestMatcher. Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.' available
2023-01-11T15:41:47.792+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-01-11T15:41:47.799+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...     
2023-01-11T15:41:47.805+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.       
2023-01-11T15:41:47.831+05:30  INFO 176088 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-01-11T15:41:47.904+05:30 ERROR 176088 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method setFilterChains in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean named 'A Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is required to use MvcRequestMatcher. Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'A Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is required to use MvcRequestMatcher. Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.' in your configuration.
```

When I uncomment this part:

```java
 @Bean(name = "mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector")
   public HandlerMappingIntrospector mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector() {
     return new HandlerMappingIntrospector();
   }
```

and run application I got no error but the application is shutting down automatically just after running:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.1)

2023-01-11T15:53:45.269+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] com.web.ecommerce.EcommerceApplication   : Starting EcommerceApplication using Java 17.0.5 with PID 177140 (C:\Users\guruk\Desktop\springboot 3\ecommerce\target\classes started by guruk in C:\Users\guruk\Desktop\springboot 3\ecommerce)
2023-01-11T15:53:45.277+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] com.web.ecommerce.EcommerceApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-01-11T15:53:45.405+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-01-11T15:53:45.406+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-01-11T15:53:46.684+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-01-11T15:53:46.783+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 87 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-01-11T15:53:47.316+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-01-11T15:53:47.404+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.6.Final
2023-01-11T15:53:47.685+05:30  WARN 177140 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
2023-01-11T15:53:47.878+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-01-11T15:53:48.292+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1fff2385
2023-01-11T15:53:48.295+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-01-11T15:53:48.393+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2023-01-11T15:53:49.209+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-01-11T15:53:49.223+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-01-11T15:53:49.925+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@62c9380d, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@338055eb, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3a2d8a59, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@50830605, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5879007b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@2bf425d7, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3022c8b8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2ae7a4be, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@39d014d1, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4bd290c2, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@43525956]
2023-01-11T15:53:50.299+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-01-11T15:53:50.462+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [  restartedMain] com.web.ecommerce.EcommerceApplication   : Started EcommerceApplication in 7.986 seconds (process running for 8.765)
2023-01-11T15:53:50.545+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-01-11T15:53:50.570+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-01-11T15:53:50.628+05:30  INFO 177140 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: You marked your tomcat dependency as provided, hence not on the classpath so it won't start a server. Which explains the first error as well as there are missing classes / beans due to no server being started.

Comment: Just a bit of context in addition to Deinum comments, the `authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(...)` creates a `MvcRequestMatcher` if Spring MVC is detected on the classpath. The `mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector` bean should be in the same `ApplicationContext` as Spring Security in order to work. It is not common having to specify the bean yourself

Comment: now its working i removed a line in application property. which  made the tomcat server  not to run.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this error by defining **mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector** bean as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
[...]
    @Bean(name = "mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector")
    public HandlerMappingIntrospector mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector() {
        return new HandlerMappingIntrospector();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
spring.main.web-application-type=NONE
```

ensure that your application properties does not have following lines its the stop the start of inbuilt server of spring boot